# Overlay on Camera using Client Side JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, opencv

I am trying to do image analysis on someone's induration (variable sized red spot on skin) after taking a Tuberculosis test to accurately determine the size.

Currently I am using NodeJS as a backend/ Web Server providing a dashboard interface and pushing images to a python script that uses OpenCV to take the left most object and a given reference size argument such as 0.955 inches for a quarter and to use that scale to measure out the other detected objects such as the induration.

The problem I am having is the red spot(induration) is not being detected properly but the quarter (reference object) is. I did a crappy fix by drawing out a line around the induration and rerunning the program and obviously this time it properly recognized the induration with the correct size.

Since this isn't a course on image analysis and I really don't have a clue to further optimize this program I was trying to figure out to provide the user with an interface to mark the induration such as a resizable circle they could put tightly around their induration.

I haven't seen any examples to do this directly using the getUserMedia() functionality on client side JS and was wondering how to go about doing this or seeing if there is some library already existing to help with this. Another option would be for the user to take the picture with the induration and quarter and then in the next step of the test on the dashboard the user has some way to draw on their image(draw a quick circle around the induration).

I have only seen ways to statically draw something on a canvas nothing with dynamic sizing and dragging the object over the image.

Appreciate any input

EDIT:
[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KWZO.jpg) is a sample image.

Here is the code currently:

```
    from __future__ import print_function
    from scipy.spatial import distance as dist
    from imutils import perspective
    from imutils import contours
    #from mysql.connector import errorcode
    from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta
    import numpy as np
    import argparse
    import imutils
    import cv2
    #import mysql.connector
    import os
        # construct the argument parse and parse the arguments
        ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
        ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required=True,
            help="path to the input image")
        ap.add_argument("-w", "--width", type=float, required=True,
            help="width of the left-most object in the image (in inches)")
        ap.add_argument("-u", "--user", required=True,
            help="Username of ")
        args = vars(ap.parse_args())



    # load the image, convert it to grayscale, and blur it slightly
    image = cv2.imread(args["image"])
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (7, 7), 0)

    # perform edge detection, then perform a dilation + erosion to
    # close gaps in between object edges
    edged = cv2.Canny(gray, 50, 100)
    edged = cv2.dilate(edged, None, iterations=1)
    edged = cv2.erode(edged, None, iterations=1)

    # find contours in the edge map
    cnts = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
        cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)

    # sort the contours from left-to-right and initialize the
    # 'pixels per metric' calibration variable
    (cnts, _) = contours.sort_contours(cnts)
    pixelsPerMetric = None
    countourCount = 0
    # loop over the contours individually
    for c in cnts:


        # if the contour is not sufficiently large, ignore it
        if cv2.contourArea(c) < 200:
            continue
        countourCount=countourCount+1
        print(countourCount)
        if countourCount == 1:
            print('This is the scaling reference, should be: '+ str(args["width"]))
        # compute the rotated bounding box of the contour
        orig = image.copy()
        box = cv2.minAreaRect(c)
        box = cv2.cv.BoxPoints(box) if imutils.is_cv2() else cv2.boxPoints(box)
        box = np.array(box, dtype="int")

        # order the points in the contour such that they appear
        # in top-left, top-right, bottom-right, and bottom-left
        # order, then draw the outline of the rotated bounding
        # box
        box = perspective.order_points(box)
        cv2.drawContours(orig, [box.astype("int")], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)

        # loop over the original points and draw them
        for (x, y) in box:
            cv2.circle(orig, (int(x), int(y)), 5, (0, 0, 255), -1)

        # unpack the ordered bounding box, then compute the midpoint
        # between the top-left and top-right coordinates, followed by
        # the midpoint between bottom-left and bottom-right coordinates
        (tl, tr, br, bl) = box
        print(box)
        (tltrX, tltrY) = midpoint(tl, tr)
        (blbrX, blbrY) = midpoint(bl, br)

        # compute the midpoint between the top-left and bottom-left points,
        # followed by the midpoint between the top-righ and bottom-right
        (tlblX, tlblY) = midpoint(tl, bl)
        (trbrX, trbrY) = midpoint(tr, br)

        # draw the midpoints on the image
        cv2.circle(orig, (int(tltrX), int(tltrY)), 5, (255, 0, 0), -1)
        cv2.circle(orig, (int(blbrX), int(blbrY)), 5, (255, 0, 0), -1)
        cv2.circle(orig, (int(tlblX), int(tlblY)), 5, (255, 0, 0), -1)
        cv2.circle(orig, (int(trbrX), int(trbrY)), 5, (255, 0, 0), -1)

        # draw lines between the midpoints
        cv2.line(orig, (int(tltrX), int(tltrY)), (int(blbrX), int(blbrY)),
            (255, 0, 255), 2)
        cv2.line(orig, (int(tlblX), int(tlblY)), (int(trbrX), int(trbrY)),
            (255, 0, 255), 2)

        # compute the Euclidean distance between the midpoints
        dA = dist.euclidean((tltrX, tltrY), (blbrX, blbrY))
        dB = dist.euclidean((tlblX, tlblY), (trbrX, trbrY))

        # if the pixels per metric has not been initialized, then
        # compute it as the ratio of pixels to supplied metric
        # (in this case, inches)
        if pixelsPerMetric is None:
            pixelsPerMetric = dB / args["width"]

        # compute the size of the object
        dimA = dA / pixelsPerMetric
        dimB = dB / pixelsPerMetric

        # draw the object sizes on the image
        cv2.putText(orig, "{:.1f}in".format(dimA),
            (int(tltrX - 15), int(tltrY - 10)), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
            0.65, (255, 255, 255), 2)
        cv2.putText(orig, "{:.1f}in".format(dimB),
            (int(trbrX + 10), int(trbrY)), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
            0.65, (255, 255, 255), 2)

        # show the output image
        cv2.imshow("Image", orig)


        cv2.imwrite(os.path.join('/Users/Ooga/Desktop/Skin-Analyzer/pythonServer/components/'+str(args["user"]) , 'component'+str(countourCount)+'.jpg'), orig)
        cv2.waitKey(0)

    # Make sure data is committed to the database
    #   cnx.commit()
```

Comment: This problem can definitely be solved in the image processing, probably with better filtering/thresholding and then some kind of detection method like canny edges, blob detection, or maybe contours. Could you post some of the image processing code you have (the Python) and give an example image?

Comment: Sure tomorrow I will post the code I am using, it is part of a tutorial I found and an example image Thank you for the response!

Comment: @MatthewSalvatoreViglione Hi I have added in the code I was referencing and an image link to an example induration. Currently if you feed that program a picture with objects that have a very clear contrast to the background it is able to detect it properly but not with an example pic like this. To avoid getting the moles the person has on his skin I am assuming is contour threshold change but I would love your take on it cause I truly don't know how to make this better.

Comment: @MatthewSalvatoreViglione Any updates?